# Cron job creates loads of records in database

Tags: error, cron

When running the following command, about 20 of the same record gets created in the database.

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

I think it's also making my plugins run the same amount of times as the record exists.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

This is the screeshot of my cron_schedule table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALgdj.jpg

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing some of the records that get created, and the XML code used to create the cron job...

Comment: I agree, this is very unclear. What database table are you even talking about?

Comment: Updated the post with screenshot of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The records are not the same, the date in the scheduled_at column is different. It seems you have defined your cronjob to run every minute, so a record is made for every minute. you have probably set your cronjob like this:

```
<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
```

Just change the first * to */5 or */15 to run it every 5 or 15 minutes, or to 0 to run every hour.

For more detailed info about setting up cronjobs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not edited any files between it working normally, and it doing this however. Which files should I look into, because it happens for every cron job.

Comment: I thought it was a custom cron job, but the cron job you are referring to is a default Magento cron job. did you set up your cron to run every 5 minutes, or do you only run it via the CLI? I think that might be the problem. just set it up to run every 5 minutes and see if it keeps generating so much records.

Comment: I'm going to set it up to ring every night at 12, although in testing stages I am doing it via CLI.

Comment: You need to run it much more often, since stuff like sending out order confirmation e-mails is also done via the cron. so it is best to set it to run every 5 minutes. You can check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html for a  more detailed list of the actions that are being performed by the cron.

Comment: I mean my plugin. I thought the Magento cron jobs are already set up?

Comment: I thought you meant the cronjob itself ( the one you manually run by typing bin/magento cron:run in the CLI). that one needs to run every 5 minutes. If you have not yet set this up correctly, you can check the link in my previous comment for info on how to set it up.